# URL Key problems on Magento upgrade 1.12 -> 1.13.1

Tags: upgrade, enterprise-1.13

I am getting this error on an upgrade, even if I drop the table, it still happens. I have checked that the table is not there prior to upgrading.

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception Object
(
    [_previous:Zend_Exception:private] => 
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity_url_key' already exists
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42
    [file:protected] => lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
    [line:protected] => 234
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
```

Comment: This seems to be related to the environment as I got the upgrade to complete on a local machine (Not on production). I will post more info as I have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake: I forgot to put the prefix in the local.xml

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by putting the prefix in local.xml. I'm encountering this same error and there isn't much else out there. Thank you. @brentwpeterson

Comment: @brentwpeterson  What does this mean about prefix in local.xml?

Comment: @Supplement I did not put in the table name prefix in my Local.xml

Comment: Do you mean this? <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix> .... i never put anything there and it usually functions correctly.. What did you have to put there? Can you give an example please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some people will use that. mage_ or magento_